# Libssh, X11 forewarding

Tags: x11, libssh

i am trying to user X11 forwarding with libssh. Because i have not found good examples for doing so, can anyone give me some example how to use X11 with libssh?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, did you find a working solution using libssh or libssh2? i filled an issue in libssh2 github account. I can't manage to get the sample code work. https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/issues/201

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the tutorial with code examples?

http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_forwarding.html

Comment: That could be an option to use the direct or inderect forewarding instead of the x11 functions in libssh. My problem still is, how can i pass the local x11 server the incomming data from the tunnel. And the other way, how can i read from the local x11 server data to pass through the ssh channel?

Answer (score 0):

I too was trying to get X11 working with libssh but had no success.  I was only able to push through regular cmds that didn't require a GUI.

If java is an option for you I would recommend the Java Secure Channel library.  Documentation isn't so good but there's an examples folder with X11 code that really helped me.  It worked great with xming.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: Well, I read the documentation, but had no success. A running example for me would be very nice. Java is not an option for me. Another option could be using another libssh library. Does anyone know a such library with an easy X11 forewarding example?

Comment: I went ahead and submitted a issue/bug in their bug tracking system: https://red.libssh.org/issues/100  I do hope for both yours and my own sake that they'll resolve it.
If you're on linux machine, you should instead take a look at libssh2.  http://www.libssh2.org/  I haven't tried it out but i did download and take a look at their example.  the C API is somewhat similar.